# Typo3 front-end login without javascript

Tags: typo3

Is it possible to do this? All existing login extensions seems to require javascript.

The reason I'm asking is because a client of mine has problem with the front-end login.
We recently changed the login extension to the felogin extension (v1.3.1) and it works great most of the times.

I never seems to have any problems but our client does. And I want to rule out the possibility that it's the javascript that breaks it.
Mostly because the client doesn't understand why the password changes when they click the login button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript is for security. It encrypts the password before it is sent to the server.
Set the setting `[FE][loginSecurityLevel]` in the install tool to anything else than RSA, and the javascript should disappear.

Comment: Just a note: if there is no RSA encryption, author should consider about using SSL at least for login page.

Comment: Thanks i'll try that. I do understand the security purposes of the javascript. I just want to rule out some variables.